# AWS Pinpoint - How to update APNs channel? How to convert a p12-certificate to String?

Tags: certificate, apple-push-notifications, channel, aws-pinpoint

I want to update the APNs channel of an AWS pinpoint application. For that I have to create a APNSChannelRequest with the SSL certificate and the certificate password. The type of the both elements must be a string.

**How can I convert the .p12-file to a string or how can I export the right key out of the .p12-file?** (This step can be done manually and does't have to be done at runtime.)

Here is the (slightly extended) example of the developer guide from AWS SDK for Java:

```
APNSChannelRequest request = new APNSChannelRequest()
    .withEnabled(enabled);

UpdateApnsChannelRequest updateRequest = new UpdateApnsChannelRequest()
    .withCertificate("here comes the ssl-certificate string")
    .withPrivateKey("pw123")
    .withAPNSChannelRequest(request)
    .withApplicationId("placeholder-for-the-appId");
UpdateApnsChannelResult result = client.updateApnsChannel(updateRequest);
```

I can't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This will require converting the contents of the p12 file to PEM format. This can be achieved via the command line using openssl as follows:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificate.p12 -nodes -clcerts
```

This will result in the CERTIFICATE and PRIVATE KEY values to be emitted in base64 format. Supply the string beginning with: `"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----"` and ending with `"-----END CERTIFICATE-----"` as the Certificate value in the `UpdateApnsChannelRequest`. Supply the string beginning with `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----"` and ending with `"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----"` as the `PrivateKey` value in the `UpdateApnsChannelRequest`.